# How to use UITableView Footer and Header to show upper and bottom borders?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to have upper and bottom borders of `UITableView`. To do so I decided to use tables header and footer with height of 1 point. I use events `viewForHeaderInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection`. My problem is that the header and footer are very thick.

I don't know if this is proper solution and I don't know how to fix the size of header and footer.

I use following code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    return view;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: add two more delegate methods `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForFooterInSection`. and return its height as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot this two methods, and both have default height:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1.0;
 }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1.0;
}
```